# How to make a dataframe in python with unique column values and value counts of a column of another dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, unique

I need to make a data frame in python using two columns, one containing unique values of one column and another column with value counts of that same unique column values. For eg., if a data frame df has columns A and B. A has values 1,2,2,3,3 and B has values "a", "b", "c". I want to make a data frame df1 with column Au as unique values of A meaning Au with values 1,2,3 and a count column with values 3,3,3 meaning count of Au duplicated the times of rows of the column Au.

example:
df:   A(1,2,2,3,3)   B("a", "b", "c")
result:  df1: Au(1,2,3)  count(3,3,3)

In this example, df and df1 are data frames and A, B, Au and count as columns of the respective data frames

Comment: If you take the time to build out some actual data frames and post the code here so we can copy/paste it and generate the same output, you will get an answer much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If we take df1 as a dataframe with 'values' as column and make a new dataframe as df:
`df = pd.DataFrame()   df['values'] = df1['values'].unique()   df['count_values'] = df['values'].nunique()`
the second line will make a column in df with unique values of 'values' column of df1 and third line will insert count values of 'values' column of df